# Syntax error at const char *sql_stmt

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql

```
-(BOOL)createDB{
        NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;
        // Get the documents directory
        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        docsDir = dirPaths[0];
        // Build the path to the database file
        databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"student.db"]];
        BOOL isSuccess = YES;
        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
        {
            const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                char *errMsg;
                const char *sql_stmt =
                "create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer
                primary key, name text, department text, year text)";
                if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
                    != SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    isSuccess = NO;
                    NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
                }
                sqlite3_close(database);
                return  isSuccess;
            }
            else {
                isSuccess = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
            }
        }
        return isSuccess;
}
```

---

Here syntax error come at

```
const char *sql_stmt = "create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer
                        primary key, name text, department text, year text)";
```

Comment: can you paste the error?

Comment: Please replace your code with this line     const char *sql_stmt = [@"create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer primary key, name text, department text, year text)" UTF8String];

Comment: What is the error ? It seems there is no issue with that line.

Comment: @MidhunMP: As it seems, that is not one line but two lines, and that is the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string constant into multiple source lines, you have to enclose
*each part* in quotation marks:

```
const char *sql_stmt =
"create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer "
"primary key, name text, department text, year text)";
```

instead of:

```
const char *sql_stmt =
"create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer
primary key, name text, department text, year text)";
```

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your code with this line

```
const char *sql_stmt = [@"create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer primary key, name text, department text, year text)" UTF8String];
```

Comment: It is not necessary to create an NSString first if all you need is a C string.