# Syntax error at *insertsql & *querysql stage

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (BOOL) saveData:(NSString*)registerNumber name:(NSString*)name
                   department:(NSString*)department year:(NSString*)year;
   {
     const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
     if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
    //here syntax error comes..
     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "insert into studentsDetail (regno,name, department, year) values ("\"%d\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",[registerNumber integerValue],name, department, year];
     const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
     sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);

     if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }else {
            return NO;
        }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
            return NO;
        }

- (NSArray*) findByRegisterNumber:(NSString*)registerNumber
     {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
          NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:"select name, department, year from studentsDetail where regno=\"%@\" ",registerNumber];
          const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
          NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

          if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                   {
                     NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                     [resultArray addObject:name];
                     NSString *department = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                     [resultArray addObject:department];
                     NSString *year = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                     [resultArray addObject:year];
                     return resultArray;
                   }else{
                      NSLog(@"Not found");
                      return nil;
                    }
                    sqlite3_reset(statement);
                }
              }
            return nil;
         }
```

Syntax error at the stage of `*insertsql & *querysql`.
Here SQL table is created dynamically & inserted values goes on sql table. I have not more knowledge of SQL.

Comment: Did you read my answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916743/syntax-error-at-const-char-sql-stmt? It seems to be exactly the same error here.

Comment: The question has been edited so that the **original problem can not be seen anymore**. (Wrong splitting of a string constant across multiple lines, same as in previous question.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this string

```
 NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "insert into studentsDetail (regno,name, department, year) values (\"\"%d\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",[registerNumber integerValue],
                                        name, department, year];
```

Comment: SQL injection alert! SQL injection alert!

Answer (score 0):

Use this string.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "insert into studentsDetail (regno,name, department, year) values (\"%d\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",num,name, department, year];
```

I think you have added extra `"` before `\"%d\"` so i have remove it in my string try that if it help.

Comment: SQL injection alert! SQL injection alert!

Comment: @trojanfoe i have just correct the string syntax error. thats all.

Comment: It's still bad practise; encourage the OP to use bind variables instead.

Comment: @trojanfoe but he has asked only for syntax error if i am not wrong.

Comment: @trojanfoe in that case i suggest OP to use FMDB wrapper for sqlite to make his work more easy.

Comment: Hi, is this answer helpful or not?